# SeekBar thumb disappear after click

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to change thumb of SeekBar from code. I want to change when someone click and I implement

```
seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

  @Override
  public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
     seek.setThumb(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red_rect));
  }

  @Override
  public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
     int progress, boolean fromUser) {
  }
});
```

At start I have default thumb and when I click it should change to red_rect, but when I click is that thumb disappear at all. Can someone help me how to solve this ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to call setBounds() on Drawable after you get it from Resources:

```
final Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.thumb);
d.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight()));
slider.setThumb(d);
```

from http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg164344.html